# Work-assigned roommate being disrespectful towards my schedule

Tags: canada, health, after-hours

I've started a job recently and to complete onsite training at the company HQ, I was assigned an apartment and a roommate. The problem is, even after defining multiple times my boundaries for sleeping, including sleeping early (a bit before 12) and not being able to sleep with much sound, my roommate has not been respectful towards my requests.

He is a late sleeper which I have no problem with, but frequently he will play video games without turning the music down or bring a friend over and talk loudly until 2 AM. At this point, I've tried ear plugs and have even recently started taking sleeping pills, even then have trouble sleeping on some of the worse nights.

At this point, my physical and mental health are beginning to suffer and am looking for solutions. I know I can sit down again with my roommate to talk about this, but I doubt he will listen for the nth time. I feel like I've exhausted methods of reasoning with him normally, and am looking for answers about if it would be worth it to escalate, and how to approach that situation.

What can I do to alleviate the situation?

Comment: how much more time do you have left to complete the onsite training?

Comment: Are you looking for situations at the workplace, such as asking your manager for a room switch, or are you looking for the best way to talk to your roommate about this? If the latter, then this question would be better suited for [interpersonalskills.se].

Comment: @MisterPositive 4 months total, 2 months left. Already the first 2 months were very taxing, and I don't see how I could handle the next 2 months without a big chance in situation, either by my roommate or just an entirely different accomodation

Comment: @DavidK I decided to post here because ultimately I've exhausted methods of reasoning with him normally, and wanted answers about if it would be worth it to escalate, and how to approach that situation

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> What can I do?

If you haven't started already, document each occurrence where your roommate disregards your needs (**the need to sleep is not trivial**).

After you have accumulated some data, I would then sit down with your roommate **one last time** and spell it all out. Review your documentation, emphasizing the impact it has on your ability to sleep, and let them know your next course of action will be to go to either your manager or in this case HR if the behavior doesn't change.

If you end up going to HR\MGR, take your documentation with you. This way they can see how serious it is (lack of sleep is *serious*) and perhaps suggest to them you get a *different, more courteous, roommate*.

Comment: I'd also make sure to document the conversations had with the roommate to show that you tried to work things out diplomatically before calling in management.

Answer (score 10):

You are experiencing an issue with a company-provided benefit, that is having a severe negative impact on your ability to do your job, and you have already made reasonable efforts to address it with the roomate and even by wearing earplugs.

It's absolutely time to go to the person managing your training and explain that the schedule incompatibility with this roomate is impeding your work performance.

Employers expecting their employees to be functional during business hours won't want them routinely being unwilling kept awake until 2am - *especially when the employer is paying to provide them with suitable housing*.  That your roomate is functional on this schedule needn't be the issue, most people could not routinely be, and wanting to be able to sleep at midnight is a very reasonable request entirely consistent with the reason the company is providing housing in the first place.